# What does this ES6 code do?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm looking over the redux todomvc example that ships with the source and there's a bit of JavaScript notation that I haven't seen before.  I'm familiar with the ES6 `export` syntax but don't understand what the export statement at the end of this code snippet is doing.  Why is the App class being combined with the result of the connect function?

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import MainSection from '../components/MainSection'
import * as TodoActions from '../actions'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { todos, actions } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <Header addTodo={actions.addTodo} />
        <MainSection todos={todos} actions={actions} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    todos: state.todos
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(TodoActions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)
```

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is two chained function calls.  `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)` is called which returns a new function value.  This second function value is called with the single argument `App`.

Using intermediary variables might help clarify what is going on:

```
let connectRet  = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
    exportedVal = connectRet(App);

export default exportedVal;
```

Comment: @Calvin currying is turning a function of multiple parameters into a chain of HoFs each of which has **exactly 1** parameter. It's not the case here, it's just a function returned from a function, nothing special (and no special term, apart of HoF).